# Haskell map function for two lists

Tags: haskell, map-function, haskell-prelude

I need to apply a function to two lists. The map function is `map :: (a->b) -> [a] -> [b]`, however I need something more like `map2 :: (a->b->c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`. Is there a prelude function similar to `map` that can do this?

Comment: you can find those easily with Hoogle (see [here](https://www.stackage.org/lts-17.13/hoogle?q=%28a+-%3E+b+-%3E+c%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Bb%5D+-%3E+%5Bc%5D)) - for example [`zipWith`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-17.13/base-4.14.1.0/Prelude.html#v:zipWith)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find such function by [hoogling `(a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20b%20-%3E%20c)%20-%3E%20%5Ba%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bb%5D%20-%3E%20%5Bc%5D). Yes, it's called [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith).